# How can connect to host's db from host?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc

I bought a Windows hosting from GoDaddy. I have configured the configuration settings(Adding database and publishing project's files to host)

I can access the database while running the project on the local server.

But when I transfer the project to the server, the project on the server can't do it.

I wrote my connection string to web.config file, here it is:

```
<add name="xyz" connectionString="Data Source=IP ADDRESS;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User ID=USERNAME;Password=PASS;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I used MVC and Entity Framework, I also used layered structure

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

try to check more details about the connection string that should be used with your database provider. [Here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) you can find several examples about how to create your connection string properly in SQL SERVER.

please notice that if you are working in your host machine, you have not to specify the IP ADDRES of your SQL SERVER but the SERVER NAME just like:

> Data Source=(SERVER_NAME) \ DB_INSTANCE_NAME

I hope that it's gonna be useful.